# Specify clickable phone-number

Tags: .net, html, mobile, communication

With `mailto:` exisits a widely available possibility to specify an email address that opens the email-client if executed.

Does exist somethin similar for phone-numbers, so that if it's used in a html-link or in a .net `Process.Start`-call, a mobile or a pc with a modem will call the specified number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per RFC2806, `tel:` - but it may not be as widely supported.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer. I have tested it on my dev-machine (modem) but sadly it has not worked neither in IE nor in .net. I will check later if it works for mobiles. Maybe in the future, the support will be broader.

Comment: Actually, the question isn't whether IE or .Net supports it, but whether there's any application at all that supports it. Applications that can't handle a URL (such as `mailto:` outside a mail program) are supposed to `ShellExecute()` it, and IE does. But if there is no Shell handler for `tel:`, such URLs cannot be handled at all.